# How to do Next/ Previous Post link inside an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm trying to got through my projects via next_post_link() function in wordpress, but I want to do it inside an anchor tag while preserving the styles applied to the anchor tag but is not working at all.

```
               <a href="<?php next_post_link(); ?>" class="next-project">next project</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing echo. Try this,

```
<a href="<?php echo next_post_link(); ?>" class="next-project">next project</a>
```

Comment: I suggest you to debug using any short of form. ex, create an dive and display the `echo next_post_link();` sample code: `<div style="border: red solid 1px;"><?php echo "<pre>"; print_r(next_post_link()); echo "</pre>";?></div>`. Hope it will help you to find where is the problem.